# Plotting Graphs R

Tags: r, graph, trigonometry

trying to plot graphs on `R`, need to plot 2 graphs in the same figure

```
f(x) = sin(x)+pi/4, -2*Pi <= x <= 2*Pi 

g(x) = {sin(x), 0<= x <= Pi or -2*Pi <= x <= 2*Pi
       {-Pi/4             elsewhere.
```

I believe I have plotted `f(x)` correctly however don't understand how to `plot g(x)` in the slightest

for `f(x)` I have:

```
t<-seq(from=2*pi, to="*pi, length=500)
plot(sin(t)+pi/4
```

Sorry unsure how to edit, edits would be appreciated.

any pointers would be great on how to plox a graph like g(x), just to let you know this is homework so not expecting anyone to do it just pointers on how to plot this sort of function would be great, thank you.

Comment: Once you use the plot function for f(x).  You'll need to use the `points` function to add the g(x) function to the original plot

Comment: okay, thank you. but I'm not sure how to even write out the g(x) function as it has the two separate plots of 0 to pi or -2pi to pi, and also -pi/4?

Comment: BTW,  you need `pi`  not `Pi`  R is case sensitive.

Comment: yes sorry i was using pi that's just how i typed it

Comment: i should be fine with adding it to the current plot however because g(x) is not just a straight forward function like f(x) i don't know how to write it out, can anyone help with that?

Comment: `-2*Pi <= x <= 2*Pi` condition supersedes ` 0<= x <= Pi` isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `curve` function:

```
curve(sin(x) + pi / 4, from = -2 * pi, to = 2 * pi, ylim = c(-2, 2))

curve(sin(x), from = 0,       to = pi,     add = TRUE)
curve(sin(x), from = -2 * pi, to = 2 * pi, add = TRUE)
```

Comment: Ah okay, I see, that's so much simpler. Thank you for your help. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to write a custom function for `g(x` and use it as `expr` in `curve` function.

```
calculate_gx <- function(x){
  ifelse(x <= (2*pi) & x >= (-2*pi), sin(x), -pi/4 )
}

curve(calculate_gx, from = -3*pi, to = 3 * pi, n = 200)
```

The result :

[image]